# use c# to open workbook with ribbon

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to write a wrapper that will open up an excel doc with macros, pass the password through, enable the macros, enable editing, and save it as a new excel sheet so that the end user can just start working with the template without all the hassle.

here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string path = @"\\\\home\\trevor$\\My Documents\\New\\_Blank_1cert.xlsm";
string savepath = @"\\\\home\\trevor$\\My Documents\\New\\"+txtName.Text.ToString()+".xlsm";

Excel.Application templatem = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook templatemwb;

templatemwb = templatem.Workbooks.Open(Filename: path, Password: "news", ReadOnly: false);

Excel.Worksheet worksheet = templatemwb.Sheets["Begin Entry"];
worksheet.Activate();        

templatemwb.SaveAs(Filename: savepath, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled);
```

Everything works as expected except that there is no ribbon at the top of the excel window.  I need the ribbon there; so how do I show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Visible property on your Application object, templatem.